# Constant DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, attributes, constants

I would like to put a constant date time in an attribute parameter, how do i make a constant datetime? It's related to a `ValidationAttribute` of the EntLib Validation Application Block but applies to other attributes as well.

When I do this:

```
private DateTime _lowerbound = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
[DateTimeRangeValidator(_lowerbound)]
```

I'll get:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property _lowerbound
```

And by doing this

```
private const DateTime _lowerbound = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
[DateTimeRangeValidator(_lowerbound)]
```

I'll Get:

> The type 'System.DateTime' cannot be declared const

Any ideas? Going this way is not preferable:

```
[DateTimeRangeValidator("01-01-2011")]
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The solution I've always read about is to either go the route of a string, or pass in the day/month/year as three separate parameters, as C# does not currently support a `DateTime` literal value.

Here is a simple example that will let you pass in either three parameters of type `int`, or a `string` into the attribute:

```
public class SomeDateTimeAttribute : Attribute
{
    private DateTime _date;

    public SomeDateTimeAttribute(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        _date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }

    public SomeDateTimeAttribute(string date)
    {
        _date = DateTime.Parse(date);
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
    }

    public bool IsAfterToday()
    {
        return this.Date > DateTime.Today;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 48):

As some of the earlier responses note, a `const DateTime` is not natively supported in C# and can't be used as an attribute parameter. Nevertheless, a `readonly DateTime` (which is recommended over `const` in Effective C#, 2nd edition [Item 2]) is a simple workaround for other situations as follows:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static readonly DateTime DefaultDate = new DateTime(1900,1,1);
}
```

Comment: although this static readonly member still can't be used in attribute parameters

Answer (score 6):

The DateTimeRangeValidator can take a string representation (ISO8601 format) as a parameter

e.g

```
                            LowerBound              UpperBound
[DateTimeRangeValidator("2010-01-01T00:00:00",  "2010-01-20T00:00:00")]
```

A single parameter will get interpreted as an **UpperBound** so you need 2 if you want to enter a LowerBound. Check the docs to see if there is a special *'do not care'* value for UpperBound or if you need to set it to a very far future date.

Whoops, just re-read and noticed

'Going this way is not preferable'

```
[DateTimeRangeValidator("01-01-2011")]
```

Why not?

Would

```
private const string LowerBound = "2010-01-01T00:00:00";
private const string UpperBound = "2010-01-20T00:00:00";

[DateTimeRangeValidator(LowerBound, UpperBound)]
```

be any worse/different than (VB date literal format)

```
private const DateTime LowerBound = #01/01/2000 00:00 AM#;
private const DateTime UpperBound = #20/01/2000 11:59 PM#;

[DateTimeRangeValidator(LowerBound, UpperBound)]
```

hth,
Alan

Comment: I know I can go this way but as stated it's not preferable...and I was wondering if I could make it a little more solid.

Comment: The advantage that the VB date literal has over using a string literal for dates, is that an issue w/ the VB date literal will result in a compile-time error, whereas an issue w/ the string literal will result in a runtime error.  That, and it also avoids an unboxing operation.

Comment: Agree on the compile-time vs run time.

Comment: What does the 'avoid an unboxing' mean? The attribute has multiple ctors, some take dates, others strings.  If the string is used there is a performance hit from the parsing, I can see that, but I don't see an unboxing problem. This is an honest question, I am not disagreeing with you, just don't fully understand the comment.

Comment: `#20/01/2000 11:59 PM#` is an invalid date literal. the order is our bad order of Month/Day/Year from the US, not the smallest to largest order of Day/Month/Year. Fortunately C# hasn't screwed this up too. But C# does need an ISO date literal. #2014-06-13# would be one great solution. I don't much of which syntax they choose, as long as they don't use the stupid Month/Day/Year order that we're stuck with in popular usage in the USA.

Comment: This answer won't work at all. You cannot set a DateTime as a constant in C#!

Answer (score 2):

DateTime types can never be a constant in C#.

Comment: False. Off course they can. Declared at class level or inside a private/public function. `const DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow();`

Comment: They most certainly cannot. 
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0283?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0283)
Try it for yourself and you'll get the CS0283 error stating such.

Comment: You are right. I even stated this in the original question . Excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

For those like me who still stumble on to this old question, this might be a solution for a `DateTime` parameter in an `AttributeValidator`:

Use the property name of the viewmodel (for example) and have the validator determine whether the value of this field is a DateTime. The property can be set in the viewmodel as an private or public field, and hold the date you want to compare it to. Then, you add the string representation of the fieldname as the property, for example with `nameof(fieldName)`. Please adjust the example below to fit your own needs with respect to what kind of comparison you want to make.

The ValidationAttribute:

```
public class DateStartEndValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
     public string CompareDateField { get; private set; }


     public DateStartEndValidatorAttribute(string compareDateField)
     {
         CompareDate = compareDate;
     }

     protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
     {
         DateTime? date = GetDate(validationContext, CompareDate);
         ValidationResult result = ValidationResult.Success;
         if (date.HasValue && value != null)
         {
             if (((DateTime)value).Date <= date.Value.Date)
             {
                result = new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName, GetDisplayName(validationContext, CompareDate)));
              }
          }

          return result;
      }

      public string GetErrorMessage(string displayName, string compareDisplayName)
      {
          if (base.ErrorMessage == null && base.ErrorMessageResourceName == null)
          {
              base.ErrorMessage = (AllowEqual ? "{0} must be equal to or later then {1}." : "{0} must be later then {1}.");
          }

          return string.Format(base.ErrorMessageString, displayName, compareDisplayName.ToLower());
     }

     private static DateTime? GetDate(ValidationContext validationContext, string propertyName)
     {
         DateTime? result = null;
         object fieldValue = GetFieldValue(validationContext, propertyName);
         if (fieldValue != null)
         {
             if (!(fieldValue is DateTime))
             {
                throw new ArgumentException("DateStartEnd comparedate property '" + propertyName + "' is not of type DateTime.");
             }

             result = ((DateTime)fieldValue).Date;
         }

         return result;
     }

     private static object GetFieldValue(ValidationContext validationContext, string propertyName)
     {
         object result = null;
         PropertyInfo property = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
         if (property != null)
         {
             result = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
         }

         return result;
     }

    // other methods
}
```

In the viewmodel:

```
Public class YourViewModel
{

   private DateTime _compareDateField = DateTime.UtcNow;

   [DateStartEndValidatorAttribute(nameof(_compareDateField))
   public DateTime DateFieldFromUI { get; set; }
   // other props

}
```

Answer (score -1):

write a method like:

```
private static DateTime? ToDateTime(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
    }
```

Now you can use strings in datarow like:
[null, "28-02-2021", "01-03-2021", 3)]

Comment: I can't see how this relates to the question. Also there is an unmatched parentheses ")" in the datarow value.

Answer (score -4):

Old question, but here's another solution:

```
 public DateTime SOME_DATE
 {
      get
      {
           return new Date(2020, 04, 03);
      }
      set
      {
           throw new ReadOnlyException();
      }
 }
```

The main advantage of this solution is that it allows you to store the date in a DateTime, not having to use strings. You can also not throw any exception and just do nothing on set if you want.

Comment: While this may fulfill part of the title of the question, it still doesn't allow you to specify a DateTime value as a parameter to an attribute.

Comment: Also, Instead of throwing an exception in the `set` clause, simply omit it. It will change the property to a readonly property and that will be enforced at compile time, which is much better than throwing an exception at runtime.