# Validating that a Reason field is filled if Date field is today

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use ASP.NET MVC4 in my solution. I have the ViewModel below where I would like to validate that the field EmergencyReason is filled only if the field Date is today. I try this:

```
public class LoadingViewModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("Date", Comparison.IsEqualTo, DateTime.Today)]
    public string EmergencyReason { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

It doesn't work. The third argument of RequiredIf must be a constant expression, ...

Any idea how can I force the user to enter an EmergencyReason only if Date field is today?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using some non-standard `RequiredIf` attribute which is not part of the standard ASP.NET MVC 4 package.

As you know C# allows you to only pass constant values to attributes. So one possibility is to write a custom attribute:

```
public class RequiredIfEqualToTodayAttribute: RequiredIfAttribute
{
    public RequiredIfEqualToTodayAttribute(string field)
        : base(field, Comparison.IsEqualTo, DateTime.Today)
    {
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public class LoadingViewModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfEqualToToday("Date")]
    public string EmergencyReason { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't support `DateTime` literals, a workaround for this is to use a `String` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859778/constant-datetime-in-c-sharp), but it won't resolve your problem. I suggest you move the validation code inside the `Controller` and return a `ModelState.AddModelError("EmergencyReason", "Emergency Reason is required")`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I would prefer a validation inside my ViewModel. If really no other solutions (answers) then I'll do it like you do.