# Using get-set to achieve const DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net

I recently found this old question asking about const DateTime in C#: [Constant DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859778/constant-datetime-in-c-sharp/60523090#60523090)

I read all the answers and they all felt like way complicated and sophisticated, and most of them forced you to store that const as a String rather than a DateTime, which I think could lead to potential issues with location settings.

My solution for this issue is using get-set clauses:

```
 public DateTime SOME_DATE
 {
      get
      {
           return new DateTime(2020, 03, 04);
      }
      set
      {
           throw new ReadOnlyException();
      }
 }
```

I was surprised that no one know thought about this. It seems like a more elegant solution. Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: Why do you have a setter?

Comment: Additionally, while it does fulfil part of what a "const" thing in C# would do, it does not fulfil all, so it might be a valid replacement in some cases, but not in others.

Comment: Since the question you link to relates to attributes, you still cannot use your approach in that case. The bottom line is that `const` `DateTime` values simply aren't legal in C# and you have to use a different type to represent your point in time if you need it to be `const`.

Comment: Also, this question is far far far too broad. "Is there something wrong with this approach". Does it compile? If yes, then the compiler says no. If you ask me? Sure, there's plenty of "wrong" things here, but that's just my opinion. Like, you should probably use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`, to make sure you're always talking about the same point in time, you don't need a setter, the naming standard is wrong, you could probably make it easier by just using a read-only field, etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

A public constant is not the same as a public readonly instance property. For starters, constants are replaced with their values at compilation - this is why they have to be literal values - and c# does not support literal values for DateTime.

Moreover, constants are static by definition - so if you wanted a property instead, you would at least have to make it a static property.

Another thing - having a setter that just throws an exception (and not even a built in exception) is just plain wrong - to make a property readonly simply don't provide a setter.

That being said, if I had to "fake" a constant for a DateTime value I would probably use a readonly static property, as it is the closest thing to a constant as you can get:

```
// Please don't use this name
public static DateTime MyAlmostConstantDateTime {get {return new DateTime(2020, 3, 4);}}
```